# Locating ArcMap Commands page

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap

If there is an updated [ArcMap Commands](http://ArcMap%2010%20Commands) site for version 10, where is it located?

I could not find it at [ArcObjects SDK 10 Microsoft .NET Framework](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the [ArcMap commands](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000n7000000) page:

> The information in this topic is useful if you're trying to
> programmatically find a built-in command, menu, or toolbar.